# How can I display values from a table that correspond to their matching id

Tags: php, html, mysql

So in this query below im joining two tables through order_id and displaying the all the values from the user_orders table.

As per the image below I am trying to display only the order_Id rows that match the order_manager table.

```php
        public function getUserOrder(){
            $sql = "SELECT user_orders.order_id, 
                            user_orders.title, user_orders.price, 
                            user_orders.quantity 
                    FROM order_manager 
                        JOIN user_orders ON order_manager.order_id = user_orders.order_id;";
                
            $stmt = $this->connect()->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->execute();
         
                    
            while ($result = $stmt->fetchAll()){
                return $result;
            }
        }
```

I have attempted to use an if statement that appears to do something however it gives me the values that don't match order id in reverse.

```php
<div class="container mt-5">
<?php $artworks = new Artworks(); ?>


    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
        <table class="table table-dark">
      <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Order ID</th>
          <th scope="col">Full Name</th>
          <th scope="col">Phone</th>
          <th scope="col">Address</th>
          <th scope="col">Orders</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
 

    
<?php
    $artworks->getOrder();
    foreach ($artworks->getOrder() as $art) {

        echo "<tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>$art[order_id]</td>
                    <td> $art[full_name]</td>
                    <td> $art[phone] </td>
                    <td>$art[address]</td>
                  
                    <td>
                        <table class= 'tale text-center table-dark'>
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope='col'>Order ID</th>
                                <th scope='col'>title</th>
                                <th scope='col'>price</th>
                                <th scope='col'>Quantity</th>
                            </tr>
                        <thead>
                        <tbody>
                <tr>";
        $artworks->getUserOrder();
        foreach ($artworks->getUserOrder() as $order) {
            if ($order['order_id'] == $art['order_id']) {

                echo "<td>$order[order_id]</td>";
            }
            echo "
                  <td>$order[title]</td>
                  <td>$order[price]</td>
                  <td>$order[quantity]</td>
                  </tr>";
        }

        echo "
            </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    ";
}
?>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Here is an image to help explain the desired output
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved moving the td items into the if statement. Guess it was mostly correct.

```
$artworks->getUserOrder();

foreach($artworks->getUserOrder() as $order)
{
    if ($order['order_id'] == $art['order_id']) {
        echo "<td>$order[order_id]</td>";
        echo "
        <td>$order[title]</td>
        <td>$order[price]</td>
        <td>$order[quantity]</td>
        </tr>
        ";
    }
}
```